# Copy the entire folder structure but filter subfolders based on the folder name by two different strings?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item

How can one copy the entire folder structure but only select some (sub-)folders based on the folder name by two different strings?

I have tried

```
PS C:\Users> $includes = "*Touch*", "*mpr*"

PS C:\Users Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Desktop\mro" -Directory |
>>     Where-Object{$_.Name -in $includes} |
>>     Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\shizzle\Desktop\shi_data6" -Recurse -Force
```

This keeps the folder structue, but copies the whole folder structure (not selected by folders containing the string "*Touch*" or "*mpr*".

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\mro' | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\Users\Desktop\shi_data9' -Recurse -Container -Filter "*Touch*"
```

doesnt work since it copies the folder and the content specifically by "*Touch*" and omits all other files (not containing "*Touch*") in the desired folder and two -filters  dont seem to work either (let alone combined with boolean (like "*Touch*" or "*mpr*"))

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how is this related to the MATLAB tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the name to be an exact match in the `$includes` array using the `-in` operator, but that array contains wildcard characters, so will not work.

Instead, use the regex `-match` operator and set your `$includes` variable to be a string with partial names separated by the regex OR (`|`) character:

```
$includes = 'Touch|mpr'
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Desktop\shizzle\mro" -Directory |
    Where-Object{$_.Name -match $includes} |
    Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\shizzle\Desktop\shi_data6" -Recurse -Force
```

---

As per your comment, Wildcard comparison is not the same as Regex comparison.

- In a Wildcard comparison (used with operators `-like` and `notlike`) the asterisk `*` means *zero or any number of ANY character*.
- In Regex, the same character has a different meaning: *zero or more of the PREVIOUS character or group of characters* <sup>(see the table below)</sup>
- Comparing literal text to find a matching string in an array as you have tried with operator `-in` does not use wildcards or regex; the string is either found literally or not.

As for the code, I have tested this (of course using different filepaths) and works, **provided** the folder for the destination of the copy already exists.
If that is not the case, start the code with

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\shizzle\Desktop\shi_data6" -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path "C:\Users\shizzle\Desktop\shi_data6" -ItemType Directory
}
```

to make sure it is created first.

Here the results of my test

**Source folder:**

```
D:\TEST
+---DoNotCopyThisFolder
|   +---SubFolder_1
|   |       File_1.txt
|   |       File_2.txt
|   |       File_3.txt
|   |
|   \---SubFolder_2
|           File_1.txt
|           File_2.txt
|           File_3.txt
|
+---mpr_Files
|   +---SubFolder_1
|   |       File_1.txt
|   |       File_2.txt
|   |       File_3.txt
|   |
|   +---SubFolder_2
|   |       File_1.txt
|   |       File_2.txt
|   |       File_3.txt
|   |
|   \---SubFolder_3
|           File_1.txt
|           File_2.txt
|           File_3.txt
|
+---NotThisOne
|   +---SubFolder_1
|   |       File_1.txt
|   |       File_2.txt
|   |       File_3.txt
|   |
|   +---SubFolder_2
|   |       File_1.txt
|   |       File_2.txt
|   |       File_3.txt
|   |
|   \---SubFolder_3
|           File_1.txt
|           File_2.txt
|           File_3.txt
|
\---Touch
    +---SubFolder_1
    |       File_1.txt
    |       File_2.txt
    |       File_3.txt
    |
    +---SubFolder_2
    |       File_1.txt
    |       File_2.txt
    |       File_3.txt
    |
    \---SubFolder_3
            File_1.txt
            File_2.txt
            File_3.txt
```

**Destination folder:**

```
D:\SHI_DATA6
+---mpr_Files
|   +---SubFolder_1
|   |       File_1.txt
|   |       File_2.txt
|   |       File_3.txt
|   |
|   +---SubFolder_2
|   |       File_1.txt
|   |       File_2.txt
|   |       File_3.txt
|   |
|   \---SubFolder_3
|           File_1.txt
|           File_2.txt
|           File_3.txt
|
\---Touch
    +---SubFolder_1
    |       File_1.txt
    |       File_2.txt
    |       File_3.txt
    |
    +---SubFolder_2
    |       File_1.txt
    |       File_2.txt
    |       File_3.txt
    |
    \---SubFolder_3
            File_1.txt
            File_2.txt
            File_3.txt
```

As for Regex, there are a few special characters that have special meaning:

**Special Characters in Regex**

| Char | Description | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \ | Backslash | Used to escape a special character |
| ^ | Caret | Beginning of a string |
| $ | Dollar sign | End of a string |
| . | Period or dot | Matches any single character |
| | | Vertical bar or pipe symbol | Matches previous OR next character/group |
| ? | Question mark | Match zero or one of the previous |
| * | Asterisk or star | Match zero, one or more of the previous |
| + | Plus sign | Match one or more of the previous |
| ( ) | Opening and closing parenthesis | Group characters |
| [ ] | Opening and closing square bracket | Matches a range of characters |
| { } | Opening and closing curly brace | Matches a specified number of occurrences of the previous |

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but, unfortunately,  this does not not copy anything. It does not throw an error but no copy takes place. May since it actually has to be a wildcard like '*Touch*|*mpr*" (which also doesnt work :)

Comment: @pythokles Please see my edit where I try to explain the difference between a wildcard comparison against a regex comparison. I also show the results of my tests. Why it does not copy anything for you is probably because in your code you have the wrong path for the originals: `"C:\Users\Desktop\mro"`, where that should be `"C:\Users\shizzle\Desktop\mro"`. You forgot the username in there.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I finally understood what the problem is. It doesnt copy anything because my actual folder structure is "C:\Users\Desktop\shizzle\mro\pre\subject_01\..." and the regex only searches the folder specified in the directory. I am sorry for the bad example, I did not think it would make a difference. Therefore, my last question would be, do you know a way to have the regex search through all the subdirectories as well and still keep the folder structure via recursive?

Comment: if I do  ```Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\copy_test\copy_test\mro" -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.Name -match $includes} | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\test_shi10" -Recurse -Force``` it again doesnt keep the entire folder structure

Comment: @pythokles I suggest you post a new question for that. Your current question has been answered and adding new requirements after that is really 'not done' on SO. In your new question, add examples, not just code to make it absolutely clear what you now have and what you would like to achieve.

Comment: You are absolutely right, this was my fault. I have now posted a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734764/copy-folder-structure-but-match-subfolders-based-on-the-folder-name-in-subdirect) and sorry again for not specifying the question correctly.