# Copy folder structure but match subfolders based on the folder name in subdirectories by two different strings?

Tags: powershell, recursion, match, get-childitem, copy-item

How can one copy an entire folder structure but only select some folders several subdirectories down based on the folder name by two different strings ('Touch' or 'mpr') ?

the files I need are in e.g.:

```
"C:\Users\Desktop\shizzle\mro\pre\subject_01\Touch"
```

but there are two Timepoint-folders (Pre and Post) and several subjects, hence I have tried a higher directory:

```
$includes = 'Touch|mpr'
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Desktop\shizzle\mro" -Directory |
    Where-Object{$_.Name -match $includes} |
    Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\shizzle\Desktop\shi_data6" -Recurse -Force
```

which works perfectly, but only if the searched folders are in the specified directory and not several subdirectories down (so it would only work in `C:\Users\Desktop\shizzle\mro\pre\subject_01`).

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\copy_test\copy_test\mro" -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.Name -match $includes} | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\test_shi10" -Recurse -Force
```

doesnt not keep up the folder structure.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\shizzle\mro\

+---pre
|   +---subject_01 
|   |   +---dontcopythisfolder
|   |   +---dontcopythisfolder
|   |   +---0024_63_Touch
|   |   |       File_1.txt
|   |   |       File_2.txt
|   |   |       File_3.txt
|   |   +---dontcopythisfolder
|   |   \---654_mpr_8364
|   |          File_1.txt
|   |          File_2.txt
|   |          File_3.txt
|   \---subject_02
|      +---dontcopythisfolder
|      +---dontcopythisfolder
|      +---0024_63_Touch
|      |       File_1.txt
|      |       File_2.txt
|      |       File_3.txt
|      +---dontcopythisfolder
|      \---654_mpr_8364
|             File_1.txt
|             File_2.txt
|             File_3.txt
\---post
   +---subject_01 
   |   +---dontcopythisfolder
   |   +---dontcopythisfolder
   |   +---0024_63_Touch
   |   |       File_1.txt
   |   |       File_2.txt
   |   |       File_3.txt
   |   +---dontcopythisfolder
   |   \---654_mpr_8364
   |          File_1.txt
   |          File_2.txt
   |          File_3.txt
   \---subject_02
      +---dontcopythis folder
      +---dontcopythisfolder
      +---0024_63_Touch
      |       File_1.txt
      |       File_2.txt
      |       File_3.txt
      +---dontcopythisfolder
      \---654_mpr_8364
             File_1.txt
             File_2.txt
             File_3.txt
```

Comment: You'll need to do string manipulation on your `-Destination` argument. `-Destination $manipulatedPath` Instead of `-Destination "C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\test_shi10"`

Comment: thanks, I have tried ```$manipulatedPath = "C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\test_shi16"``` and ```Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\copy_test\copy_test\mro" -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.Name -match $includes} | Copy-Item -Destination $manipulatedpath -Recurse -Force``` but no dice unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$sourcePath  = 'D:\Test'  # 'C:\Users\Desktop\shizzle\mro'
$Destination = 'D:\Data'  # 'C:\Users\shizzle\Desktop\shi_data6'
$includes    = 'Touch|mpr'
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse -Directory |
    Where-Object{$_.Name -match $includes} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($sourcePath.Length)
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetPath -Recurse -Force
    }
```

Instead of using the `Substring()` method above, you can also use regex `-replace` to construct the target path.
However, keep in mind that a path contains characters that have special meaning for regex, so you should then use the `[regex]::Escape()`'d version of the source path, and anchor it to the beginning of the string with `^`:

```
$sourcePath  = 'D:\Test'  # 'C:\Users\Desktop\shizzle\mro'
$Destination = 'D:\Data'  # 'C:\Users\shizzle\Desktop\shi_data6'
$includes    = 'Touch|mpr'

# if you want to use regex `-replace` instead, use this:
$escapedSource = '^{0}' -f [regex]::Escape($sourcePath)
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse -Directory |
    Where-Object{$_.Name -match $includes} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath ($_.FullName -replace $escapedSource)
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetPath -Recurse -Force
    }
```

Below the results of my test (using different paths of course..)

**Source**

```
D:\TEST
+---post
|   +---subject_01
|   |   +---0024_63_Touch
|   |   |       File1.txt
|   |   |       File2.txt
|   |   |
|   |   +---654_mpr_8364
|   |   |       File1.txt
|   |   |       File2.txt
|   |   |
|   |   +---dontcopythisfolder
|   |   \---ignorethisonetoo
|   \---subject_02
|       +---0024_63_Touch
|       |       File1.txt
|       |       File2.txt
|       |
|       +---654_mpr_8364
|       |       File1.txt
|       |       File2.txt
|       |
|       +---dontcopythisfolder
|       \---ignorethisonetoo
\---pre
    +---subject_01
    |   +---0024_63_Touch
    |   |       File1.txt
    |   |       File2.txt
    |   |
    |   +---654_mpr_8364
    |   |       File1.txt
    |   |       File2.txt
    |   |
    |   +---dontcopythisfolder
    |   \---ignorethisonetoo
    \---subject_02
        +---0024_63_Touch
        |       File1.txt
        |       File2.txt
        |
        +---654_mpr_8364
        |       File1.txt
        |       File2.txt
        |
        +---dontcopythisfolder
        \---ignorethisonetoo
```

**Destination**

```
D:\DATA
+---post
|   +---subject_01
|   |   +---0024_63_Touch
|   |   |       File1.txt
|   |   |       File2.txt
|   |   |
|   |   \---654_mpr_8364
|   |           File1.txt
|   |           File2.txt
|   |
|   \---subject_02
|       +---0024_63_Touch
|       |       File1.txt
|       |       File2.txt
|       |
|       \---654_mpr_8364
|               File1.txt
|               File2.txt
|
\---pre
    +---subject_01
    |   +---0024_63_Touch
    |   |       File1.txt
    |   |       File2.txt
    |   |
    |   \---654_mpr_8364
    |           File1.txt
    |           File2.txt
    |
    \---subject_02
        +---0024_63_Touch
        |       File1.txt
        |       File2.txt
        |
        \---654_mpr_8364
                File1.txt
                File2.txt
```

Comment: Thaaaaank you so much, this worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant by string manipulation, try this and see if it works:

```
$basePath="C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\copy_test\copy_test\mro\"
$includes = 'Touch|mpr'
$destinationPath="C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\test_shi10"

Get-ChildItem $basePath -Recurse -Directory |
    Where-Object{$_.Name -match $includes} | %{
        $manipulatedPath=Join-Path $destinationPath -ChildPath ($_.FullName -replace $basePath)
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $manipulatedPath -Recurse -Force
    }
```

Edit:

For the sake of testing, I have a lot of folders inside a test folder (disregard their names) and will attempt this copy without actually copying the folder but to see what their "Destination Path" would be. Here is the code:

```
$basePath='/home/zen/Documents/test'
$destinationPath="/home/zen/Desktop/copied_folders"
$i='#'*30

"
$i
My Test Folders:
"
(Get-ChildItem $basePath -Recurse -Directory).FullName

"
$i
My Destination Folders:
"
Get-ChildItem $basePath -Recurse -Directory | %{
        $manipulatedPath=Join-Path $destinationPath -ChildPath ($_.FullName -replace $basePath)
        $manipulatedPath
    }
```

Here is what my PS Host shows me as the supposed destination Paths:

```
PS /home/zen> /home/zen/Documents/script.ps1

##############################
My Test Folders:

/home/zen/Documents/test/emptycompressedfolder
/home/zen/Documents/test/Folder with Spaces
/home/zen/Documents/test/INC.
/home/zen/Documents/test/RESIDENCES
/home/zen/Documents/test/emptycompressedfolder/emptyfolder
/home/zen/Documents/test/emptycompressedfolder/emptyfolder/emptyfolderinsideemptyfolder
/home/zen/Documents/test/emptycompressedfolder/emptyfolder/emptyfolderinsideemptyfolder/insideemptyfolder
/home/zen/Documents/test/emptycompressedfolder/emptyfolder/emptyfolderinsideemptyfolder/insideemptyfolder/insideeeee

##############################
My Destination Folders:

/home/zen/Desktop/copied_folders/emptycompressedfolder
/home/zen/Desktop/copied_folders/Folder with Spaces
/home/zen/Desktop/copied_folders/INC.
/home/zen/Desktop/copied_folders/RESIDENCES
/home/zen/Desktop/copied_folders/emptycompressedfolder/emptyfolder
/home/zen/Desktop/copied_folders/emptycompressedfolder/emptyfolder/emptyfolderinsideemptyfolder
/home/zen/Desktop/copied_folders/emptycompressedfolder/emptyfolder/emptyfolderinsideemptyfolder/insideemptyfolder
/home/zen/Desktop/copied_folders/emptycompressedfolder/emptyfolder/emptyfolderinsideemptyfolder/insideemptyfolder/insideeeee
PS /home/zen>
```

Comment: unfortunately, I cant get it to work. The ```get-Childitem``` command gives me this error ```The regular expression pattern C:\Users\shizzle\Downloads\copy_test\copy_test\mro is not valid.
At line:3 char:9
+         $manipulatedPath=Join-Path $destinationPath -ChildPath ($_.Fu ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\Users\shizzl...t\copy_test\mro:String) [],RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression```

Comment: Not sure why it would not be working for you, but check out my edit

Comment: thank again for your help, it is very strange but I am still getting the same error when I run your test code (it somehow thinks the manipulated or base path are a regex pattern (error message above when executing ```Get-Childitem```)).